# Why do i get the default value back?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

On my SettingsActivity i am saving a value with the following code:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("ClassName", strArrClasses.get(i));' // i is a variable inside a loop
int intClassID = i+1;
editor.putInt("ClassID", intClassID);
editor.commit();
```

I'm now trying to get the value of the SharedPreference with the Key "ClassID" on my MainActivity with the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int intClassID =  sharedPrefs.getInt("ClassID", 543548564);
```

My problem now is that I cant access the class ID and I am always getting the default value.

Edit:

I already checked if i can get the ClassID on my SettingsActivity and that works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead. Like

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

as from document [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29)

> getPreferences retieves a  SharedPreferences object for accessing
>   preferences that are private to this activity. This simply calls the
>   underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this
>   activity's class name as the preferences name.

and `getSharedPreferences` retrieve `SharedPreference` by the name.

In your case you used `getPreferences` which returned `SharedPreferences` of those activities only.

Comment: I also need to edit my editor to
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
right?

Comment: yes.. get the sharedpreference by getsharedpreferences method of same name.